# Error while trying to add BlossomV package in Julia

Tags: julia, build-error, precompile, ioerror, enoent

I am trying to add the BlossomV package in Julia. I am receiving the following error:

```
*LoadError: BlossomV not properly installed. Please run Pkg.Build("BlossomV")

LoadError: Failed to precompile BlossomV*
```

On running `Pkg.Build("BlossomV")`,

I am getting the following error:

```
*LoadError: IOError: could not spawn setenv(*A lot of attributes are there here*): no such file or directory (ENOENT)*
```

I am facing this error on both Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

I would appreciate it if anyone could explain what the issue is and how to solve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

BlossomV.jl is just a wrapper around a C library and I bet it is the process of building the C library that's failing. BlossomV is designed around the old approach to handling binary dependencies. It would be great to either rewrite it using pure Julia, or use the modern ["artifact" system](https://julialang.org/blog/2019/11/artifacts/) which is a vastly more robust way to ship binary dependencies.